# compile error - object required

Tags: vba, object, compilation, required

I cannot find any errors in my code, however the "object required" error keeps coming up.
Can somebody please help. I have been on this, trying to fix it for half an hour and I still cant find the problem. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

```
Private Sub cmdCost_Click()

Dim strCost As Integer
Dim strFixedCost As Integer
Dim strResourceCost As Integer
Dim wksResources As Worksheet

Set wksResources = Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Resources")
Set strFixedCost = 140


If cResources.Text = "" = False Then
If Val(tQuantity.Text) > 0 Then

wksResources.Select
wksResources.Range("B2").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = cResources.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Set strResourceCost = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value

Set strCost = strFixedCost + (Val(strResourceCost) * tQuantity)

MsgBox " The price is" & " $" + strCost, Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Cost"

Else
MsgBox " You have not chosen a quantity.", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Cost"
End If
Else


MsgBox " You have not chosen a resource.", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Cost"
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: which line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

I could see a few issues with your code:
1. You are using 'Set' to initialize strCost, strFixedCost & strResourceCost which is not required. Just write:

```
strFixedCost = 140
```

2. Also, your 1st IF condition is quite confusing. I suppose you are checking if value is present in cResources variable (you haven't mentioned where you are getting cResources & tQuantity values). in that case you can just use `If Len(cResources) > 0 Then`
3. Your 1st msgbox will give you a type mismatch error as you are combining string with an integer.

   MsgBox " The price is" & " $" + strCost, Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Cost"

Instead you can use the below code to convert strCost to string:

```
MsgBox " The price is" + " $" + CStr(strCost), Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Cost"
```

Comment: thanks for your help ! i have one more error now. a type mismatch error. however it is in this code.

strCost = strFixedCost + ((strResourceCost) * tQuantity)


where strCost, strFixedCost and strResourceCost are integers and tQuantity is a value from a textbox on my userform.

Comment: try using Cint(tQuantity) function and store it in a integer.